# Select Text with Context menu support third-party app in Flutter

Tags: flutter

1. Google Translate app is inserting the context menu item in the context menu of different apps.
2. SelectableText gives {copy,select all}
3. How to leave the context menu in a flutter with support for the Google Translate application?

Example
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKQtR.jpg